# Angular2 — как не потерять связь стилей при подключении компонента?

Tags: javascript, css3, html5, angular2

Здравствуйте.

Суть вопроса:

```
<div style="display: flex">
<app-component><!-- Внутри флекс элементы --></app-component>
</div>
```

В таком случае, связь теряется и флекс-элементом становится `<app-component>`, а не то, что внутри.
Вопрос: Как это исправить? Компонент должен остаться директивой.

Comment: никак, если у тебя app-component действительно компонент - просто выставь display:flex непосредственно у него, без всяких внешних дивов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использование хоста - отличный вариант:

```
...
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  templateUrl: '...',
  host: {
    'class': 'app-flex-style'
  }
})
export class AppComponent {
  ....
}
```